# Java application to start a process and get a callback when events occurred in process

Tags: java, events, callback

*My requirement is to start a process from java and register for events callback for the process for eg: like started or killed.*

#### Typical scenario:

In my GUI application, I have a "start process" button with "start/running" status text. I want the status to dynamically change when the process is running or not running.
I don't want to continuously check for the list of process and query for my process but a way the callback is triggered when the process is completed.

Comment: If callbacks is not the feasible way any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and unrefined solution - Java8 - (just in case, for the unaware: see [java.lang.Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Process.html) and [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) on how to start one)

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class ProcessObserver
implements Runnable {
  protected Consumer<Process> callback;
  protected Process           toExecute;


  public ProcessObserver(
    Consumer<Process> callback, 
    Process toExecute
  ) {
    super();
    this.callback = callback;
    this.toExecute = toExecute;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while(this.toExecute.isAlive()) {
      try {
        this.toExecute.waitFor(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        this.toExecute.destroyForcibly();
        return; // Honouring the interrupt request,
                // bail out here and don call the callback
      }
    }
    this.callback.accept(this.toExecute);
  }

  static public void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPoolExecutor pool=new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        4, 1024, // the threads will mostly sleep in waitFors
        3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
    );

    Process longRunningProcess=null; // initialize it properly
    ProcessObserver observer=new ProcessObserver(
      (Process p)->System.out.println("Exit code of: "+p.exitValue()),
      longRunningProcess
    );
    pool.execute(observer);
  }
}
```

A more refined solution will involve a single thread monitoring multiple processes polling them periodically and invoking the associated callback for those that exited (after all, a 0.2s-1s delay in reporting the exit code for long running processes won't make too much of a difference).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to this:

```
public interface Callback{
    public void executeCallbackActions();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Callback callback = new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void executeCallbackActions() {
            System.out.println("Who pressed the button?");
        }
    };

    runGui(callback);
}

public static void runGui(Callback callback){
    //When button is pressed
    callback.executeCallbackActions();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use processbuilder like below

```
public class ProcessBuildDemo {
   public static void processdone() {
        System.out.println("processing is done....");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
       String[] command = {"notepad.exe"};
        ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );
        Process process = probuilder.start();
        // 
        // set status of you button as process is runnning

        //Read out dir output
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n",
                Arrays.toString(command));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        //Wait to get exit value
        try {
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();
          //set status of you button as process is stop or do call function
            processdone();                  
            System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```